# If $T$ is a projection and $||Tx|| \leq ||x||$ for $x \in V$, then $T$ is orthogonal projection

Tags: linear-algebra, orthogonality

I know how to prove if T is orthogonal projection, then $||T(x)|| \leq ||x||$

but the converse one is quite challenging
Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: The quickest approach here is to use Schur decomposition.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Hint** Let $U=Im(T)$ be the subspace on which you project.

To prove that $T$ is an orthogonal projection, you need to prove the following:

If $v \perp U$ then $T(v)=0$.

The conclusion follows from here by writing the orthogonal decomposition of $x$ with respect to $U$ and observing that for $x \in U$ you have $T(x)=x$, since $T$ is a projection.

Assume by contradiction that $T(v) \neq 0$ for some $v \perp U$. Let $w =T(v)$.

Then 
$$w \in U, v \in U^\perp$$

Let $x:=sw +v$. Then by orthogonality 
$$\|x\|^2=s^2\|w\|^2 +  \| v \|^2$$
$$\|T(x)\|^2=\|sw+w\|^2=\|w\|^2(s+1)^2$$

Now, your condition Yields:

$$2s\|w\|^2 \leq \|v\|^2-\|w\|^2$$

Now pick the right $s$ to get a contradiction. This is possible because $\| w\| \neq 0$.

Comment: where is the $t$ and $u$ come from on your last fourth lines?

Comment: @SophiaHua Fixed it now.

Comment: It seems that you proved that if $x$ in range $T$, then $x$ in Null space of $T$, so we have range($T$) is contained in null($T$). Do we need also prove that null($T$) is contained in range($T$) as well ?

Comment: @SophiaHua Write $x=x_U+x_\perp$ the orthogonal decomposition of $x$. I proved that $T(x_\perp)=0$. Now, $x_U \in Im(T)$ and $T$ is a projection, so what is $T(x_U)$?

Comment: @SophiaHua An no, I didn't prove $Range(T) \subset Null(T)$. I proved $Range(T)^\perp \subset Null(T)$.

Comment: Oh, right its the complement $Range(T)^{\perp} \subset Null(T)$. But we still have to show that $Null(T) \subset Range(T)^{\perp}$ ?

Comment: @SophiaHua Why? As I sugested , use the orthogonal decomposition now.

Comment: I was following the definition of orthogonal projection on my textbook, which states that  $T$ is orthogonal projection if $Range(T)^{\perp} = Null(T)$

Comment: @SophiaHua If you want to prove it that way, if $T(x)=0$ then $T(x_U)+T(x_\perp)=0$. We proved that $T(x_\perp)=0$, therefore $T(x_U)=0$. Since $x_U \in Range(T)$, show that this implies that $x_U=0$. This means that $x =x_\perp$ which proved the identity you want.

Comment: lol, thanks so much , have already figured out every single piece of the proof now.